# Java Regular Expressions Not Compiling - No Match Available Error

Tags: java, regex

I have been working on this project which requires converting a file to a string and then finding the locations of certain strings within the string. I am trying to use the Pattern and Matcher classes to do this. Please take a look at my code below (java):

```
String begin = "TOSS-UP" + "\\s*" + j;
String end = "TOSS-UP" + "\\s*" + (j+1);
Pattern beginPattern = Pattern.compile(begin);
Pattern endPattern = Pattern.compile(end);
System.out.println(beginPattern);
Matcher beginMatcher = beginPattern.matcher(input);
Matcher endMatcher = endPattern.matcher(input);
int beginPosition = beginMatcher.start();
int endPosition = endMatcher.start();
```

where j is a variable in a for loop (that starts out at 1 and works its way up to 24) and input is a string that starts out as such:

ROUND 1 TOSS-UP 1) ... TOSS-UP 2) ... TOSS-UP 3) ... TOSS-UP 4) ...

I need to use regex since every so often this string will have a \n between the TOSS-UP and the number (instead of a simple space).

I'm new to regex, trying to learn what I can off internet examples, and I can't see why this program can't compile. The error eclipse gives me is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available 
at java.util.regex.Matcher.start 
at Driver.main
```

Any help fixing the regex would be appreciated. If anyone else has another solution to the problem, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You must call `matches()` or `find()` before you can call [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#start--). Javadoc even documents this: *Throws `IllegalStateException` **if no match has yet been attempted**, or if the previous match operation failed.* Javadoc of [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) says: *Once created, a matcher can be used to perform three different kinds of match operations: The `matches` method [...] The `lookingAt` method* [...] The `find` method [...].*

Comment: Even after doing so, I still get the same error. I used the find method.

Comment: Did they return `true`, indicating a *successful* match? You can't ask for match result values until you have successfully performed a match. Makes sense, right?!? --- It's like asking for an apple, being told that there aren't any, then asking how big they are. It is an unanswerable question, which is why you get an exception.

Comment: Wait, after using find it started partially working (doesn't go through all of the string, still finds the same error after a while, but works for some of it). Let me go through and try to understand why it's stopping at the point that it is and I'll get back to you.

Comment: After some quick modifications, looks like it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `matches()` function first, before trying to get anything from the matcher object. Calling `matches()` will trigger the match, and a boolean value returned depending on whether there was a match or not.

```
... // as usual
int beginPosition = -1;
int endPosition = -1;
if(beginMatcher.matches()) {
     beginPosition = beginMatcher.start();
} 

if(endMatcher.matches()) {
    endPosition = endMatcher.start();
}
```

As pointed out by @MikeSamuel in the comments, if you want only the first match, perhaps `.find()` would be better. Also, consider adding a `\b` to the end of your regex so `TOSS-UP 1` is not found in `TOSS-UP 10`, for example.

Comment: `.matches()` matches the entire string.  Maybe `find()` would be better though in that case you would probably want a `\b` after the number so that `TOSS-UP 1` is not found in `TOSS-UP 10`.